# NFA designing for strings starting with $01$

Tags: finite-automata, transition-systems

The question was asked

> Construct an NFA with set of all strings that start with $10$.

The solution provided to me is
[image]

But my question is what if the automaton receives an input $0$ at the starting? Also there is no option for $q_1$ to transit after receiving $1$. So I think the solution should be

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an NFA, the solutions are equivalent. When you are in a state without any transition for the current input you receive, you terminate (equivalent to getting stuck in a non-accepting state without going out of it).

Comment: so what i did is a DFA?

Comment: Yes, but since a DFA is also an NFA, you can technically say its also an NFA